# MYSQL SELECT FROM two tables and cutting down queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, woocommerce

I have two tables `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy`

When I do the following `SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = '17'` I get the image below

[image]

Then I do `SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE  term_taxonomy_id  = '28'`

Which outputs

[image]

The `object_id` then gets used `SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE  object_id  = '88'` and this shows me the `terms` for this item.

[image]

What I would then like to do is show next to `term_taxonomy_id` the `taxonomy` name from the following table

[image]

I apologise this is a long winded question but I hope there are people who would be able to help and possibly simplify it so that from my initial query of where the `parent=17` I am able to only show DISTINCT `taxonomy` of where the `taxonomy` is equal to `product_brand`

Comment: You want to _only show DISTINCT taxonomy of where the taxonomy is equal to `product_brand`_. Wouldn't this only return one record where the value of `taxonomy` is the value `product_brand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your last query by:

```
SELECT wptr.*, wptt.taxonomy
FROM wp_term_relationships wptr 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wptt ON wptr.term_taxonomy_id = wptt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE object_id = '88'
```

It uses an INNER JOIN that will take the taxonomy name from wp_term_taxonomy for the term_taxonomy_id ID.

As Anticom said, you should have a look at the JOIN in SQL, they would solve your problem and are easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem are [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). You could use [subselects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) aswell but joining tables usually is faster.

There should be similar developer resources to other DBMS like MSSQL or PostgreSQL etc.